# missing wedge in matplotlib contourf plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, contour

I'm trying to plot a contour plot in matplotlib and I keep getting a missing "wedge". The following example illustrates what I'm trying to do.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ph_cut = 0.05
nphi = 13
phi = np.linspace(ph_cut,2*np.pi-ph_cut, nphi)

nr  = 50
rmax=1
rr  = np.linspace(0, rmax, nr)
PH, RR = np.meshgrid(phi,rr)

X = RR * np.cos(PH)
Y = RR * np.sin(PH)
Z = np.sin(PH)

nlev = 13
levels=np.linspace(-1, 1, nlev)

cs=plt.contourf(X,Y,Z, levels)

plt.colorbar(cs)
plt.show()
```

The wedge between -ph_cut and ph_cut is never filled. Is there no way for matplotlib to interpolate across? Strictly speaking, this region is no different and has no less information than the corresponding pi-ph_cut to pi+ph_cut... I tried searching around but could not find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't leave out the cut:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ph_cut = 0.05
nphi = 13
phi = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi, nphi)

nr  = 50
rmax=1
rr  = np.linspace(0, rmax, nr)
PH, RR = np.meshgrid(phi,rr)

X = RR * np.cos(PH)
Y = RR * np.sin(PH)
Z = np.sin(PH)

nlev = 13
levels=np.linspace(-1, 1, nlev)

cs=plt.contourf(X,Y,Z, levels)

plt.colorbar(cs)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I'm aware of that solution. My real issue is with another dataset, though, which I can't just fill in the missing cut. The example above was the simplest minimal example I could create that reproduced the same problem.

Comment: So you are saying that the code you posted replicates the display __not__ the problem!

Comment: No, the code posted does replicate the problem. I have a similar dataset which is indeed missing a small cut, and which I would like matplotlib to interpolate across when doing the contour plot. If I plot the very same data in IDL, for instance, IDL does interpolate when making the contour plot and no missing wedge is displayed.

Comment: The code I posted is the simplest minimal working example I could create. I see no reason for matplotlib not to interpolate since, in the example I posted, the region between phi=0.05 and phi=0.565 (say), should be equivalent to the one between phi=-0.05 and phi=0.05. See what I mean?

Comment: You are specifically telling __not__ to fill in the gap!

Comment: How would I tell matplotlib to fill in the gap, then? I guess another way to ask the question is as follows: I have a 2D polar dataset that spans phi = epsilon, ..., 2*pi - epsilon, like in my example above. I would like to make a contour plot that covers the full circle. IDL's contour plot does this (filling in the wedge between 2*pi-epsilon and epsilon), with the very same dataset. Can I achieve this with matplotlib?

Comment: Probably the easiest way is to provide some data for the region +/- epsilon in that way you can control the exact interpolation method used - since you are the one providing the rest of the data you should have some idea whether the data is discontinuous at that point or not - of course if your data is from a measurement you could actually measure what is happening at that point.

Comment: The data is the result of a simulation, which for technical reasons is restricted to phi=eps,...,2*pi-eps. Everything should be continuous there. The reason I would expect matplotlib to interpolate across is the following: in my example above, I create an array PHI=[phi_1,phi_2,...,phi_N]. Now, when I plot sin(PHI), matplotlib fills in the contour between phi_1 and phi_2, between phi_2 and phi_3 and so on, even though it has **no** information about what happens in the middle. Using the same reasoning, it should be able to fill the region between phi_N and phi_1. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: In that case why not add a data element after your last either ε or (2π-ε) that is at (2π-ε) or ε as appropriate and contains the value that you already have for (2π-ε) or ε?